# How do I set a wpf text box to resize automatically when the user changes the size of dialog box?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I set a wpf text box to resize automatically when the user changes the size of dialog box?

```
 <Window x:Class="MemoPad.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Background="LightGray" 
    Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="700" >
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock ="Right">
        <MenuItem Header="Find" x:Name="gMNuFind" />
    </Menu>
    <Button Content=" Find " 
          Margin="5,10,5,5"
          x:Name="gBuFind" 
          />
    <TextBox Margin="0,0,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          MinHeight="270" MinWidth="690"                  
          x:Name = "gTBxInfo" 
          TextWrapping="Wrap"
          AcceptsReturn="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or change StackPanel to Grid

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Background="LightGray" 
    Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="700" >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Find" x:Name="gMNuFind" />
        </Menu>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content=" Find " 
          Margin="5,10,5,5"
          x:Name="gBuFind" 
          />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          MinHeight="270" MinWidth="690"                  
          x:Name = "gTBxInfo" 
          TextWrapping="Wrap"
          AcceptsReturn="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What does the "1" do for the last RowDefinition Height?

Comment: look here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/
In row / column definitions you can use fixed size, auto or ratio factor (1*)

Comment: Something new for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `MinHeight` and `MinWidth` from the `TextBox`, and change `HorizonalAlignment` to `Stretch`

```
<TextBox Margin="0,0,0,0"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"               
  x:Name = "gTBxInfo" 
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  AcceptsReturn="True"
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

**Edit:**

If you want to resize the `TextBox` in both directions (horizontally and vertically), you would have to use a different container other than `StackPanel`, so that the `TextBox` sizing is independent.

Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Find" x:Name="gMNuFind" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Menu>
    <Button x:Name="gBuFind" 
            Content=" Find " 
            Margin="5,10,5,5"     
            Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name = "gTBxInfo" 
             Margin="0,0,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"               
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it stretch by default?

Comment: @d.moncada I've tested your solution and `TextBox` doesnt fill the whole area. It only resize horizontally not vertically

Comment: @rraszewski I didn't realize you wanted it to resize both ways. I'll update

Comment: @d.moncada I dont know ttom intentions, but i thought that _resize automatically when the user changes the size of dialog box_ means resizeing in both dimensions.

Comment: @rraszewski, I fixed the sizing issue. though, for a second I thought you were OP.

Comment: @d.moncada hmm... It looks very similar to my solution below..  But now it looks good for me.